# How to validate passowrd like it must have to be one alphabet and one number in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need jquery validation for password
I need jquery regular expression which have at least one alphabet and one number.
I tried this `/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/;` regular expression but it doens't work when i add special characters in it, does anyone have idea about this type of regular expression, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you should look into is [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/). A simple jQuery library for validating strings (min, max etc). And after a quick google, I found plenty of other people with the same question as yours. Here's one: [jQuery Validate plugin - password check - minimum requirements - Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746234/jquery-validate-plugin-password-check-minimum-requirements-regex).

In this question, @Bergi gives an answer with the following regex

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]+$/
```

The min and max attributes are being handled via validate.js. Hope this helps!