# Setting the Password complexity

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

For setting the Password complexity in .Net MVC web application, how can I achieve the following rules:

1) Password must not contain significant portions (three or more contiguous characters) of the name. (this point is not available in that linked post)

2) At least three of the following four categories:

- English uppercase characters (A through Z)
- English lowercase characters (a through z)
- Base 10 digits (0 through 9)
- Non-alphabetic characters: ~!@#$%^&*;?+_

I would like to achieve this using javascript/jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Why javascript? You can do this better with annotations in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Wouldn't a minimum length be more useful than the characters from each category concept? What is "name"? The user's name?

Comment: @MacakM- how ? can you please explain ?

Comment: @nnnnnn- password should be minimum 8 characters in length and maximum 10 characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate plugin - password check - minimum requirements - Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746234/jquery-validate-plugin-password-check-minimum-requirements-regex)

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan- does that post/question has requirement of following point ?

"1) Password must not contain significant portions (three or more contiguous characters) of name."

Comment: Maximum 10? Please no. Allow at least 20-something for users that want that. (And I assume you're not storing the unhashed passwords in your database?)

Comment: @nnnnnn- not possible to increase the maximum length than 10.

Comment: why marked this question as 'unclear or not useful' ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to use javascript for this purpose (it can be bypassed). Better solution is to use ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations. With them you can set attributes to your model class and when is POST operation triggered, it will validate the input based on this attributes.

You can learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

You can also write your custom validation attribute based on your needs. In your case I think the **[RegularExpression]** attribute would be sufficient for 2).

For 1) you should make your custom attribute as is shown in here:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc-4-custom-validation-data-annotation-attribute/

Comment: @MacakM- do you think that i can achieve my 1st point through this [RegularExpression] attribute ??

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that point... does it mean that password for user MacakM can't  be aca5842?

Comment: for e.g: name=MacakM, so password cant have any of the 3 continuos characters from the name 'MacakM'. Like valid password = Ab1@h2s5.
Invalid password = AbMac5s because it has 'Mac' of name.

Comment: Yes, then you should use your custom attribute as I wrote in answer. You simply write there what you want to validate and return true/false :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I will take a look at the suggestions and see if I can get them working :)

Comment: Good luck, don't forget then mark the answer that helped you :)